# Ask browser to not download / show images

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, browser

I'm using:

```
var do_it = setInterval(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 100000000000000); }, 2000);
```

to trigger the Infinite Scroll to load a very big page, for scraping purposes.

**Is it possible to ask Chrome to not download / show images** to save RAM, CPU? (the browser begins to be very slow when scrolling a lot and loading a very long page)

Comment: chrome://settings/content/images

Comment: Add a css rule to give images `display:none` in some browsers this prevents them from being downloaded at all, I think it works in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Before do_it() is called, you can set the src attribute of all images to null, so no image will be shown and no requests will be fired:

```
$('img').attr('src','');
```